# Facebook Status Update Doesn't Show Thumbnail

Tags: share, facebook-opengraph

Although the Facebook Debugger is showing the correct thumbnail for: http://www.apparelyzed.com/forums/topic/26287-burned/

When this url is entered into the profile update, it only fetches the text, and not the meta-image as well.

Thanks

Simon

Comment: This is the og: code on my forum pages:   
  


<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.apparelyzed.com/forums/public/style_images/master/meta_image.png"/>

Comment: Sorry, having difficulty in posting the url, but it is valid.

Answer (score 1):

In the above given page source has a this link tag and has an image. What is the purpose of this image. Try removing this link and see.

```
<link rel="image_src" ref='http://www.apparelyzed.com/forums/public/style_images/master/meta_image.png' />
```

and also check that your image size is minimum 50x50 and its good to have 200x200

The og:image property has some optional structured properties:

```
 1. og:image:url - Identical to og:image.
 2. og:image:secure_url - An alternate url to use if the webpage
    requires HTTPS.
 3. og:image:type - A MIME type for this image.
 4. og:image:width - The number of pixels wide.
```

Comment: google:"image_src" http://stackoverflow.com/a/19274942 it is currently (or was and not working anymore) the only way to specify a preview image with relative URL. Because specifying URL with domain requires dirty hacks while using CDNs in some frameworks.