# What is <link rel="image_src">

Tags: html, xhtml

Today I came across a `<link rel="image_src">` tag. I don't know about it, so I use google. Google tell me that this tag are similar to `og:image`. So I came to open graph main site to read about it http://ogp.me/, but i found nothing about link `rel="image_src"`. So this tag is replacement to meta `property="og:image"` or is in special tag in another specification ? How use this tag or for what is used?

Comment: Actually, I think that was the old way of determining which image was picked up by scrapers / crawlers like Facebook.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The `rel` attribute specifies the type of the link, i.e. the kind of the relationship between the document and the linked resource. Usually just a few keywords, like `stylesheet` and `icon`, are used. Although many other keywords have been proposed and registered, most of them are write-only: they are meant to express something, but nobody cares (no software uses the information).

The extension mechanisms of HTML5 include, in the description of [link types](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes), a somewhat obscure mechanism that allows, in theory, anyone register his favorite keyword in the [existing rel values wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/rel) to make documents using it as `rel` value “conforming”.

And `image_src` has indeed been registered there, with the information that it is used to “specify a Webpage Icon for use by Facebook, Yahoo, Digg, etc.”, no specification has been identified but an [article](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2009/03/enhanced-social-share.html) about it is linked to, and it is “probably redundant with rel=icon”.

Comment: "probably redundant with rel=icon" Other websites like maybe want to display a teaser image in contrast to a simple icon.

Comment: About the last paragraph: Facebook has used this for years to generate link thumbnails when og:image is missing, and still do.

Comment: Facebook does not use it anymore.

Comment: The facebook lint (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/) is using it today

Answer (score 8):

You can use this tag to use an image as the thumb for link share.

Answer (score 3):

When someone posts a link to your site on social media, such as Facebook, the image that is displayed with your link is usually the first one in your code.  This may not be the image that best fits defines your site, and it may not fit well in the small box that Facebook posts.  The link rel="image_src" tag lets you control what image (or images, you can have more than one by stacking separate references) is displayed alongside your link.