# Why use <link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" ...>?

Tags: html, ios

While I was looking at the HTML source for my [favorite website](https://stackoverflow.com/), I noticed that it's using

```html
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon image_src" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
```

Obviously the second link has something to do with Apple's iOS, but why isn't `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">` sufficient?  What is special about iOS that it has a dedicated html link rel tag?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

iOS has a concept of "Web Clips" for Web sites and applications. There are two main front-facing parts to an iOS Web application's presence on an iOS device: its Home screen icon (or the Web Clip icon), and its startup image. These are represented by `apple-touch-icon` and `apple-touch-startup-image` respectively.

The main differences between traditional favicons and Home screen icons are:

- Home screen icons are of a higher resolution. Even the smallest possible icon size, 29x29, is larger than the traditional favicon size, which is 16x16. Favicons in ICO format can have hi-res alternatives, but they weren't very well supported at the time iOS introduced Web Clips anyway.
- iOS prior to 7 would apply a gloss effect to icons by default to make them look at home on a Home screen. To give developers the option of turning this effect off Apple provided another possible value, `apple-touch-icon-precomposed`. Of course, in iOS 7 these effects are no longer ever applied, but that's how it was previously.

Since Home screen icons are so fundamentally different from favicons, it doesn't make sense to try and make existing shortcut icon schemes work on iOS. Hence, `apple-touch-icon` (and `apple-touch-icon-precomposed`).

And of course, following the introduction of the iPad and the Retina display (and a combination of both), Home screen icons now come in all sorts of sizes. Now that Apple has its own icon type to work with it can simply introduce its own `sizes` attribute for supplying different icon files for different sizes.

More details about Web apps in iOS can be found in the Safari Web Content Guide, particularly the section [Configuring Web Applications](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html).

Answer (score 23):

When Mac iOS users bookmark or save a website to their iOS system, by mobile device, etc, the webpage is saved to the home screen as a screenshot of the page, which can be very unflattering.

Setting up an Apple Touch Icon for your website will over-all boost the visual optimization of your website for iOS users, which can be very flattering..

**Apple Touch Icon Sizes**

- 144 x 144 is the perfect size for iOS with retina displays. Icons
  will be compressed for other devices.
- 72 x 72 is used on iPads and 114 x 114 is used on iPhones.

Focus All devices

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/custom_icon.png"/>
```

Focus Multiple Devices

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png" />

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="touch-icon-ipad.png" />

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="touch-icon-iphone4.png" />

<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="touch-icon-retina-ipad.png" />
```

Comment: Where did you get those sizes from? I realise this is an old post.
https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/icons-and-images/app-icon/

Comment: Another question why does it need these different sizes? Most probably they were resize version of a an original larger version. Is the IPhone iPad not able to resize a larger version to a smaller one? The added bandwith usages of the additional formats most probably would outway the speed difference observed client side. It would however add to network bandwidth and cost (as in real cost on a limited bandwith service)

Answer (score 5):

It's the image you can see if you add the website to your home screen.

See the [Safari Web Content Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html) for details.

Answer (score 1):

All the current answers only partially reply to the question. They explain the meaning of `apple-touch-icon` but not the meaning of `image_src`.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19274942/6267288) helped me to understand the meaning of `image_src`. Here is what he said:

> And `image_src` has indeed been registered there, with the information that it is used to “specify a Webpage Icon for use by Facebook, Yahoo, Digg, etc.”, no specification has been identified but an article about it is linked to, and it is “probably redundant with rel=icon”.

I would add to this answer `image_src` is the recommended image to use when we want to represent the website when PNG image is supported for icons. While `rel=icon` is the legacy way to do - probably when the application (ie: browser) does not support png.

Comment: That's the exact opposite of reality. `image_src` isn't standard, `rel=icon` is. Facebook will fallback to using `image_src` if it must for rich snippets. It has nothing to do with icons.